# Accessing upgradable packages using 'apt list --upgradable' from Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, apt

I'm attempting to access the list of upgradable packages on my host system from within a Docker container using **`apt list --upgradable`** to export the count of upgradable packages as a metric.

I've tried mounting **`/var/lib/apt`**, **`/var/cache/apt`** and **`/etc/apt`** into the container, but I'm still unsure if I have all the necessary directories mounted to retrieve this information completely.

Here's an example command I'm using to run the container:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/apt:/var/lib/apt \
           -v /var/cache/apt:/var/cache/apt \
           -v /etc/apt:/etc/apt \
           -it --rm ubuntu:22.04 apt list --upgradable
```

Despite mounting these directories, when I execute **`apt list --upgradable`** within the container, I'm not getting the expected list of upgradable packages. Is there anything missing or any additional steps needed to retrieve the full list of upgradable packages using **`apt list --upgradable`** from within a Docker container?

Any suggestions, insights, or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does `apt-get update` within the container help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. While it updates the apt repositories of the host, it doesn't change the result of `apt list --upgradable`. The result is still different from inside the container.

Comment: I tried to debug this problem by running `sudo strace -f -e open,openat,openat2 apt list --upgradable > 2>&1 | grep -v /var/lib/apt | grep -v /var/cache/apt | grep -v /etc/apt` in order to find directories that apt is using that your bind mounts have not covered, but none of the files it's accessing seem relevant to your question.

Comment: Oh Nick, thanks! You put me on the right track! The directory `/var/lib/dpkg` has to be mounted into the container as well. Thanks!

Comment: One of the major goals of running software in a container is that it can't manipulate the system software of the host.  Why can't you directly run `apt-get` commands on the host?

Comment: I agree with you. That's why I mount those host volumes as read-only. The above command was just for demo purposes. 
As you already said the isolation is just one goal of container, but they also offer other benefits like control over the main process of the container, resource allocation and orchestration, self-heal, etc. In my case I'm running a custom node-exporter to expose prometheus metrics from the underling host via a daemonset. Running this exporter inside a container make the whole management and deployment much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of @Nick ODell.

The directory `/var/lib/dpkg` has to be mounted to get the right result from `apt list --upgradable`. None of the other directories is needed.